# There exists $\delta>0$ with $D_{\delta}(z_0)$ such that $f(z)\neq f(z_0)$ for all $z\in \partial D_{\delta}(z_0)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be analytic on $\Omega$ open, and assume that $f$ is not
>   identically a constant on $\Omega$. Let $z_0\in \Omega$. Prove that
>   there exists $\delta>0$ such that $D_{\delta}(z_0)\subseteq\Omega$ and
>   $f(z)\neq f(z_0)$ for all $z \in\partial D_{\delta}(z_0)$. Also, show
>   that $\min_{z\in\partial D_{\delta}(z_0)}|f(z)-f(z_0)|>0$

My attempt on proof uses the following theorem:

> Identity principle: Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ be domain and
>   $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ analytic. If there exists an infinite
>   sequence ${z_k}\subseteq\Omega$, such that $f(z_k)=0$, for all
>   $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $z_k \rightarrow z_0\in \Omega$, then $f(z)=0$ for all
>   $z\in\Omega$.

My attempt:

So assume $f$ is not identically constant, which implies $f\not\equiv0$ and suppose there exists no such $\delta$. i.e., there exists $z\in D_{\delta}(z_0)$ such that $f(z)=f(z_0)$ for any $\delta>0$. Let $\delta=\frac{1}{n}$ for $n$ large so $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}z_n=z_0\in\Omega$ where $f(z_n)=0$ for each $n$. We can do this because there exists $z_0\in \Omega$ such that for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$, $f(z)\equiv0$ on $|z_n-z_0|=\delta$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}|z_n-z_0|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$, in other words, $\lim_n{n\to\infty}z_n=z_0$.Then by identity principle, $f\equiv0$ which is a contradiction to our initial assumption.

I feel like I'm missing some pieces. Please enlighten me if I am, or please let me know whether I'm on the right path. Also, I'm having trouble showing $\min_{z\in\partial D_{\delta}(z_0)}|f(z)-f(z_0)|>0$

Comment: You are writing $f(z_n)=0$ instead of $f(z_n)=f(z_0)$. You have to apply identity theorem to the analytic function $g$ defined by $g(z)=f(z)-f(z_0)$. The last part follows from the f cat that the minimum value is attained by compactness of the circle and continuity of the function.

Comment: For the identity principle, I see the “if” but not the “then.”

Comment: You need $\Omega$ to be connected.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you. I can see why showing $f(z_n)=0$ isn’t relevant in this case. But does my logic flow look correct?

Comment: @YaG Your logic is correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Would you be able to explain a little bit more about attaining the minimum value?

Comment: @YaG $|f(z)-f(z_0)|$ is a continuous function on $\partial B_{\delta} (z_0)$ so it attains its minimum value at some point $z_1$. But its value at any point is $>0$ so the minimum is $>0$.